# 'In Container.php Class view does not exist', after running make:migration - Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I've been trawling for almost two days to find an answer, but no solutions to similar problems have helped to solve mine, so time to ask my own question.

Using Laravel 5.7 on Windows 10. When I run a `php artisan make:migration` command, or make a model with a migration (`make:model -m`), it runs fine once; the migration is created. But after that I am unable to run any further php artisan commands. Every time I try I get:

> In Container.php line 779:
>
> Class view does not exist

I've since discovered that the same issue also arises when making a seeder. I have noticed that upon running the first command, the `bootstrap\cache\services.php` file is being removed. Using a backup to replace this file in the directory fixes the problem, allowing me to run php artisan commands again. But the moment I make a migration or a seeder, the file is removed and I encounter the same error.

- I have tried a `composer dump-autoload`. If the services.php file is in the directory, it gets removed again and I am shown the error.
- I have tried `composer update` and `composer install` (including after removing the vendor folder)
- I have tried `php artisan config:cache` and `php artisan config:clear`
- I have checked my .env file for spaces not contained within quotations.
- I have checked that 'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,' is in my config\app.php file under 'providers'.

Everything seemed to be working fine a week or so ago. I hadn't been running any php artisan commands in the interim or really working directly with my application at all during that time so I am not sure what has caused this issue to arise.

Comment: Do you tried to disable your antivirus software?

Comment: It was working fine about a week or so ago... but I tried disabling my anti-virus and no change.

Comment: Try moving all your code to new Laravel 5.7 Install and test again.

Comment: I have actually tried that, but I appreciate the suggestion.
Do you think it'd be worthwhile to perform a complete xampp / composer / laravel reinstall? Because I've been considering it.

Comment: Okay and yes that would be one of the solution, let me know.

Comment: Complete reinstall of everything has seemed to fix the problem.

However, I created a migration that I needed to delete. I was under the impression that running `composer dump-autoload` after this was the best practice, but this removed that file once again. So I deleted the laravel project and created **another** new one. As long as I don't run that specific command perhaps I'll be alright.

But there's still an underlying issue...

Comment: Nope, the problem came back.
I ran a migration of the migrations I had made so far to test that everything was formed correctly. Then I created a new migration and once that had been created, the services.php file vanished and I am getting the error.

Comment: What antivirus do you have installed on your computer?

Comment: I have AVG. What makes you think it's related to the antivirus?

Comment: Because Avast antivirus will delete my server.php in Laravel application, so this might be the same issue.

Comment: Have you found a way to stop that from happening?
In my case when I run a php artisan command, I can see the services.php and the packages.php files vanish from and reappear in the bootstrap/cache/ folder right before the command finishes running and I can begin entering a new command. But then at some point after a command, the services.php file stops reappearing and I can't run any more php artisan commands.

Comment: Yes I manage to stop it in my end, I just disabled the antivirus and it works fine. 

Try checking the artisan command source code to see if you found causing the issue.

Btw, how many developer working on that project?

Comment: Its just me on this project.
Where would I even begin to look in the source code? For myself, the appeal of Laravel is that it does a lot of the heavy lifting for me and that I don't necessarily need to understand the specifics of how that is working.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to run this command:

sudo chmod 777 -R bootstrap/cache

Comment: I'm using windows 10. 

Also, I understand that giving 777 permission is bad, as it gives full permissions to everyone. Probably not too big of a concern while Im only in a local environment, but don't want someone in a production environment to stumble upon this.